# Did black misplay here or did I miss something?

Tags: combinations

I'm getting back into chess after a hiatus of 8+ years, so I'm a bit rusty. This position is from a game I just played online.

I'm white and it's my move. I threaten black's rook and knight with `Qd5`, and this is how it played out. I'm amazed it worked in my favor, because as far as I can tell, instead of `3. - a6`, he could have moved `3. - Qf6`, which would save him after a few exchanges. Am I missing something, or did he just make the wrong move?

EDIT: Removed irrelevant sentence about Kf7.

```
r1b1kbnr/p1pp4/1p6/4nP1p/6pq/2N5/PPP1BPPP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 0 1

1. Qd5 Nc6
2. Bb5 Nge7
3. Re1 a6
4. Bxc6 dxc6
5. Qxc6+ Bd7
6. Qxa8+ Kf7
7. Qxa6
```

Comment: @bof or 7. Qxc8+ right away, since the black knight is pinned.

Comment: @GloriaVictis Was 2...Nge7 the best Black could do? What happens if he plays 2...Nf6?

Comment: @bof seems like a much better move to me; I'd say white maintains an edge after 3. Re1+, but I do not see an immediate win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw in your game `a6` failed terribly as it's simply inviting white to take on `c6` and win the rook. Black had a better way of avoiding all of this a move earlier, i.e. `2. Bb5 Nf6` instead of `Nge7`. See illustration:

```
r1b1kbnr/p1pp4/1p6/4nP1p/6pq/2N5/PPP1BPPP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 0 1

1. Qd5 Nc6
2. Bb5 Nf6
3. Re1+ Kd8
4. Qd2 (4. Qd3 Bc5) (4. Qc4 Bc5)
```

Finally as for `Qf6`, as has been suggested in comments by others, it simply loses to `Ne4` (or the engine move which is `Bf4`, but it doesn't matter as `Ne4` is good enough):

```
r1b1kbnr/p1pp4/1p6/4nP1p/6pq/2N5/PPP1BPPP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 0 1

1. Qd5 Nc6
2. Bb5 Nge7
3. Re1 Qf6
4. Ne4 Qf7
5. Bxc6 dxc6
6. Qe5 Bg7
7. f6
```

So both `a6` and `Qf6` blunder the game away, the former bit more horribly so.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked his way of avoiding the `Nge7` pin. Fortunately, he did too. Thank you for the clear explanation and illustrations.

Comment: In your second variant, what happens if black plays 4. ... Qd4 or Qe5?

Comment: I believe instead 2.Bb5 white could simply play 2.Re1 first. Maybe I will answer this sometime soon by explaining why Bb5 is not so good and how Black can defend and improve its position

Answer (score 0):

In the initial position I would chose White. Black is slightly ahead in material, but most of it is a dead wood.

3. ... Qf6 loses to 4. Ne4, e.g. 4. ... Nd5 5. Nf6++ K~ 6. Nd5 recovering material.

Comment: Isn't there 5.Nd6++ Kd8 6.Rd8 mate?

Comment: I was looking at 4.Ne4 Qf7 5.Bxc6 dxc6 6.Nd6+ cxd6 7.Qxc6+ Kd8 8.Qxa8 Nxf5 9.Bg5+ and White can grab the a-pawn.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster 5. ... Kf7 is technically legal

Comment: @user58697: Not according to the rules I know … ;-)

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster Sorry I might be under influence; tell me how f7 is controlled?

Comment: The variation I'm talking about is 3…Qf6 4.Ne4 Nd5 5.Nd6++ (now f7 is controlled by the Nd6) Kd8 6.Re8#

Comment: Yes, 4...Nd5?? is a horrible blunder. 4...Qf7 puts up a better fight.